# VBA public string not saving

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I'm trying to automatically save a file using public variables in two separate functions, but for some reason my public variable doesn't seem to be saving.

After I assign my public variable `gammaSheet` a value in `ImportGammaData()`, the function works in properly assigning `Sheets(wkbkSheet).Name = gammaSheet`.

`MsgBox(gammaSheet)` also displays the proper string.

Unfortunately, when I try to use `gammaSheet` in `SaveAs()`, it has no value.

`MsgBox(gammaSheet)` displays absolutely nothing.

What's going on?

```
Public gammaSheet As String
Public radionuclide As String
Public radioligand As String
Public studyCond As String
Public studyDate As String
Public folderName As String
Public studyName As String
Public gammaFile As Excel.Workbook
____________________________________________________ 
Sub ImportGammaData()

Dim wkbkSheet As String
wkbkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(6).Name
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkbkSheet).Range("A1:L105").Value = ""
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkbkSheet).Range("A1:L105").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Dim gammaFileName As String

Dim starting_file_directory As String
starting_file_directory = Range("E3").Text
ChDrive starting_file_directory
gammaFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Gamma counter file for study sheet")

Set gammaFile = Workbooks.Open(gammaFileName)

With ActiveWorkbook

gammaSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Range("A1").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(41, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
    :=True

Range("A3:A8").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A3"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(31, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
    :=True

Range("A10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A10"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(23, 1), _
    Array(32, 1), Array(42, 1), Array(51, 1), Array(61, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wkbkSheet).Range("A1:I105").Value = gammaFile.Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("A1:I105").Value

End With

gammaFile.Close savechanges:=False

Sheets(wkbkSheet).Name = gammaSheet

Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("A10:I10").Font.Bold = True
Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("J10") = "Sample ID"
Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("J11") = "Cs-137"
Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("J12") = "Ge"
Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("J13") = "Background"
Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("K10") = "Volume (µL)"
Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("L10") = "ACN (µL)"

Sheets(1).Range("A16").Value = gammaSheet

Sheets("Decay Correction").Range("C2").Value = Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("C1").Value

If Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("B6").Value = "C-11" Then
    Sheets("Decay Correction").Range("B3").Value = "t(1/2) of C-11"
    Sheets("Decay Correction").Range("C3").Value = "20.385"
End If

If Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("B6").Value = "F-18" Then
    Sheets("Decay Correction").Range("B3").Value = "t(1/2) of F-18"
    Sheets("Decay Correction").Range("C3").Value = "109.77"
End If

Sheets(1).Range("B6").Value = "GAMMA COUNTER FILE IMPORTED!"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B6").Interior.ColorIndex = 50

radionuclide = "[" + Sheets(gammaSheet).Range("B6").Value + "]"

End Sub
____________________________________________________ 
Sub SaveAs()
Sheets("Initial").Select
folderName = Range("A20").Value
studyName = Range("A16").Value + " " + Range("B16").Value + " " + Range("C16").Value + " " + Range("D16").Value + " " + CStr(Range("E16").Value) + " " + Range("F16").Value

'Dim strPath As String
'strPath = "C:\Users\tyeg\Documents\Gamma Counter Processing" & folderName
'Dim elm As Variant
'Dim strCheckPath As String
'
'strCheckPath = ""
'For Each elm In split(strPath, "\")
'    strCheckPath = strCheckPath & elm & "\"
'    If Len(Dir(strCheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strCheckPath
'Next

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\tyeg\Documents\Gamma Counter Processing\" + folderName + "\" + studyName + ".xlsm"

MsgBox (gammaSheet)

gammaFile.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\tyeg\Documents\Gamma Counter Processing\" + folderName + "\" + gammaSheet + ".T"

End Sub
```

Comment: Something is resettting the value of your global between calling `ImportGammaData` and `SaveAs`.  Either the VBProject is getting reset (which clears all globals) or some other code is actively clearing the value of `gammaSheet`

Comment: Where (in which module) is this code written in, who's calling it, and does anything anywhere use the `End` instruction?

Comment: I suppose you removed the instruction that assigns `gammaFileName`? Because otherwise the `Set gammaFile` instruction would fail. Did you otherwise "clean up" your code before posting? e.g. removed `On Error Resume Next` instructions by any chance?

Comment: Does your code even compile? There's no `End With` following the `With ActiveWorkbook` and in any case you're not actually using any members of the `With ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @ThunderFrame I think OP tried to "clean up" their code for posting, and inadvertently removed the key to the problem. *And* made the code uncompilable.

Comment: Woops, yeah I tried to clean up my code because honestly `ImportGammaData` is SUPER long. I'll post the full code when I get into work in a few hours.

Comment: Ok, I just posted my full code. It's probably really overwhelming, but hopefully it would help to better pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: I found out that the values of global variables of a workbook are wiped out after you do `.SaveAs` on that workbook. I think this is the root of the issue for me.

Answer (score -3):

Make `gammaSheet` a global variable. Global variables keep their value after execution. In this case, after taking the value in `ImportGammaData()`, you will no have trouble when you recall the value of `gammaSheet` from `SaveAs()`.

Change this:

```
    Public gamaSheet As String
```

To this:

```
    Global gamaSheet As String
```

Comment: `Global` is deprecated and does **EXACTLY** the same thing as `Public`, except `Public` can also be used in class modules. OP's variable is therefore *already* global, and this code changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: Though deprecated, "Global" is still VALID. I have had this kind of trouble before, and this is how I solved it.

Comment: The point is that it's IDENTICAL to `Public` everywhere it's VALID. So whatever you *think* you fixed with that, `Global` didn't fix it all by itself. Go ahead, try to reproduce that problem and fix it by replacing `Public` with `Global`. Include the repro in your answer and I'll happily remove my downvote. Otherwise, this answer is spreading misinformation and relies on magic. BTW, OP's variable is `gammaSheet`, not `gamaSheet`.

Comment: Hey Victor, I appreciate you trying to help even though it didn't work! Sorry you got downvoted so much :(